Laravel 11, Spatie multi-tenancy queues are not triggered
Im using Laravel 11, with Spatie/Multi-tenancy package. to create a multi tenancy SaaS application.
Here is my database.php
   'tenant' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DB_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => null,
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'),
        'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],

    'landlord' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DB_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => 'landlord_db',
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'),
        'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],

multitenancy.php
 'tenant_finder' =>  Spatie\Multitenancy\TenantFinder\DomainTenantFinder::class,
 'switch_tenant_tasks' => [
    // \Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\PrefixCacheTask::class,
     Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchTenantDatabaseTask::class,
    // \Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchRouteCacheTask::class,
],
'tenant_model' => Tenant::class,

'queues_are_tenant_aware_by_default' => true,

'tenant_database_connection_name' => 'tenant',

/*
 * The connection name to reach the landlord database.
 */
'landlord_database_connection_name' => 'landlord',

env file
   DB_CONNECTION=tenant
   DB_HOST=mysql_db
   DB_PORT=3306
   DB_DATABASE=landlord_db
   DB_USERNAME=root
   DB_PASSWORD=root

app.php, please let me know if the middleware are correct also
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
->withRouting(
    web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
    api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',
    commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
    health: '/up',
)
  ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->api(append: [
          \Spatie\Multitenancy\Http\Middleware\NeedsTenant::class,
           \Spatie\Multitenancy\Http\Middleware\EnsureValidTenantSession::class,
          \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ]);
})
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {

 })

my issue is queues are not triggered:
    php artisan queue:work

Please let me know if I forgot something, or im missing anything.
error StackTrace:
[2024-09-20 20:05:25] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (Connection: tenant, SQL: select * from `jobs` where `queue` = high and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= 1726862725) or (`reserved_at` <= 1726862635)) order by `id` asc limit 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 3D000): SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (Connection: tenant, SQL: select * from `jobs` where `queue` = high and ((`reserved_at` is null and `available_at` <= 1726862725) or (`reserved_at` <= 1726862635)) order by `id` asc limit 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:825)

[stacktrace]

In the jobs table of your database is there anything in the queue column other than default? If so you need to list them when running the queue, in the order of priority php artisan queue:work --queue=high,medium,default,low

@JonMenard. in the landlord database jobs table there is the following columns :
id, queue, payload, attempts, reserved_at, available_at, created_at

@JonMenard. Question updated ( please check error stack trace )

Are there any rows in that table at the moment?  Any rows are pending items the queue will process. In any given row, the value of queue is the name of the queue. That queue needs to be running for them to be processed

'database' => null in your tenant config need to be updated to the correct database name

@JonMenard. no rows yet, since i just created a user ( job must be triggered ) normally

@JonMenard:   database must be null, because system must switch to the database in question ( should not be fix )

I assume you followed the instructions at https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v4/installation/using-multiple-databases ?

@JonMenard I did but I will double check again

My guess is there is an issue with "Automatically switching to the database of the current tenant"

just checked again : same config

I agree, but i dont know why. weird

in your config/multitenancy.php
do you have
'switch_tenant_tasks' => [         Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchTenantDatabaseTask::class,     ],

@JonMenard. Yes i do

@JonMenard I will update my question to share my multitenancy.php with you

in your .env can you set DB_CONNECTION=landlord 

@JonMenard. I did tried that also,   but now he is looking for the tables inside landlord_db  ( normally should look in tenants table )
Table 'landlord_db.orders' doesn't exist

did you add a tenant to the landlord database?

yes I do have 2 tenants ( tenant1. database and tenant2 database)

bootstrap/app.php can you add Illuminate\Support\Env::disablePutenv(); before $app is defined

@JonMenard
same issue, tried with both connections landlord and tenant :(
I mean I know where the issue is located
normally the queues are saved in the landlord_db.jobs table. BUT its not switching to the default connection which is landlord so we can store the job there
1 - request is coming from tenant1.localhost. that means we are pointing on database tenant1.    while the jobs should be saved in landlord_db

are you running php artisan optimize:clear when changing the configs? if not try that just to make sure everything is being reloaded

@JonMenard I do that always, tried also again now :(

@JonMenard. pelase double check my app.php (middlewares)
